# Javascript can you merge multiple `.replace()` methods?

Tags: javascript

For the first time ever, I have the need to manipulate a string quite heavily in JS. After playing around I've noticed how out of hand it can get. I'm no JS pro and I'm guessing there's a cleaner way to achieve my desired output?

**Question:**
Is editing the sample string `x`, like I have done necessary or is there a better solution?

> My goal is to go from this:  `_postcode_pricing_manual_weekend_evening`
> to this:  `Manual Weekend Evening:`

```js
const x = '_postcode_pricing_manual_weekend_evening'; // Original String
console.log("Original:", x);

var str = x.replace('_postcode_pricing_',''); // Strip prefix
console.log('1:',str);

var finalStr =  str.replace(/_/g, ' '); // strip Underscores
console.log('2:',finalStr);

// Add ':'
finalStr = finalStr += ':';

// Split into words array
const words = finalStr.split(" ");

// Loop array capitalise first letter of each word '[0]'
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);
}

// Put array back together.
console.log("Final output:",words.join(" "));
```

Comment: You can daisy chain the `.replace()` calls since it always returns a string.

Comment: There really isn't a "cleaner" way to do this in Javascript (or any other language with immutable strings, which is almost all of them). You can extract some helper functions like `capitalizeFirstWord` rather than just doing imperative manipulations or chain the method calls as Terry suggests, but that's about it.

Comment: I see, well thanks for the assist. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can chain methods, so long as the previous method returns a type that implements the next method in a chain.

As for your process, you have some redundancy. You replace underscores with spaces, but then discard those spaces with your `split()` call. You could simply split on undercscores.

```js
const x = '_postcode_pricing_manual_weekend_evening'; // Original String
console.log("Original:", x);

const words = x
  .replace('_postcode_pricing_','')                   // remove prefix
  .split("_")                                         // split into words
  .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)) // capitalize
  .join(" ");                                         // rejoin
 
console.log(`${words}:`);                             // final literal adding ':'
```

Another option would be to use a regular expression in the second replace, [passing a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters) as the second argument to transform each matched character.

```js
const x = '_postcode_pricing_manual_weekend_evening'; // Original String
console.log("Original:", x);

const parsedString = x
  .replace('_postcode_pricing','')
  .replace(/_(\w)/g, (_, firstChar, offset) => 
    (offset > 0 ? ' ' : '') + firstChar.toUpperCase());
    
console.log(`${parsedString}:`);
```

Comment: So much cleaner than my initial attempt. Brilliant, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If by "merge" you mean chain multiple `replace`s together, yes.

`str = x.replace('_postcode_pricing_', '').replace(/_/g, ' ') + ':'`

...is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It's cleaner than my attempt . I'll take it. Thanks.

Comment: You can even chain the split and the join, and use 'map' as well, and do everything including the capitalization all in one go, no `for` loop needed.

Comment: I didn't even think about using `map`, good point.